# ¿Como puedo convertir mi string a valor booleano?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un Json que contruyo dinamicamente e imprimo el valor de un botón.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero pasar de `string` a `boolean` los "false" y "true" que imprimo. Lo he intentado asi, pero todo lo vuelve `true`

```
Boolean($(this).val())
```

Comment: Si dices que construyes el `Json` por qué no lo creas con los valores boleados directamente?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es generar una pequeña condición por cada propiedad, cuyo resultado será un `Boolean`, de la siguiente forma:

```js
const objeto = {
  access: "TRUE",
  create: "false"
}

let access = (objeto.access.toLowerCase() === "true");
let create = (objeto.create.toLowerCase() === "true");

console.log(access, create)
```

Agregué el método [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/toLowerCase) para asegurar que funcione independiente de si los valores del objeto están en mayúsculas o en minúsculas.

Comment: Le agregaría un `.ToLowerCase` para que todo vaya fresh~

Comment: @fredyfx pero que excelente comentario bro, lo voy a añadir en el ejemplo!!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer una pequeña función para estarte evitando generar una condicional con la comparación de textos por cada variable o valor.

```
strABooleano: function(cadena){
    switch(cadena.toLowerCase().trim()){
        case "true": case "yes": case "1": return true;
        case "false": case "no": case "0": case null: return false;
        default: return Boolean(cadena);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sería bueno que citaras la fuente de donde sacaste [la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1414175/3791844).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con una función simple

```js
const strToBool = str => {
  switch(str.toLowerCase()) {
    case "true":
      return true;
    case "false":
      return false;
    default:
      return;
  }
};

console.log(strToBool("true"))
console.log(strToBool("false"))
console.log(strToBool("FALSE"))
console.log(typeof strToBool("false"))
```

Haremos un switch que detecte si hemos recibido `true` o `false` como string (si no ha recibido nada o un valor distinto se no se devolverá nada) y devolverá el valor en booleano